# How to disable Grails Jasypt plugin encryption during integration tests?

Tags: grails, jasypt

Is there a way to disable encryption, or possibly use a trivial algorithm during integration testing of a Grails project? There is quite a bit of overhead in the field level encryption that doesn't necessarily need to be tested then and simply adds to the time taken to run the tests.

Excluding the plugin during the test phase probably won't work since mapping is required and will likely break the compile.

I'm thinking a plain text or simpler algorithm might work, or would it be possible even to have a config ignore the encryption processing all together?

The goal is simply to reduce the performance hit of the plugin during tests.

Comment: Is it that big of a perf hit?  I'm curious if you remove the plugin and run your integration tests how much of a difference there is, is it more than a couple of percent?  You also run the risk of missing overflow issues in your integration tests if you turn it off (as the encrypted values are longer than non-encrypted ones)

Comment: I've done some small scale tests of an author with first/last name encrypted and doing a simple list of 1000 encrypted objects takes me 3s on my box while the unencrypted equivalent takes 0.3s. When loading just one record, encrypted takes 6ms vs 1ms non-encrypted. With all the tests we're doing I think it could shave off quite a bit.

Comment: The overflow issues are a good thing to keep in mind though.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative that could help would be to turn down the keyObtentionIterations in dev (it's a config value).  This is the number of iterations that the encryptor does to make it much harder to crack, as it recursively encrypts that many times to slow things down.

Change this in your config:

```
keyObtentionIterations = 1000
```

to

```
keyObtentionIterations = 1
```

(if you have it set, otherwise add it).  That should speed things up significantly and still keep it so that overflow issues are still tested.

If that does help, I'd be curious to hear how much that speeds things up if you could reply with speed differences.

Comment: Lowering the iterations did not make a significant difference. I'm playing around with a custom string encryptor which helps but not to the percentage I was hoping for. I think it's because the hibernate session isn't clearing during most tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Category to stub out encryption. But you will have to measure which one is a perf hit (Category or Encryption).

`class EncryptionCategory {

```
static String decrypt(PBEStringEncryptor obj,String encStr) {
    return encStr
}

static String encrypt(PBEStringEncryptor obj,String str) {
    return str;
}
```

}`